# How to set margin to main ConstraintView in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layoutparams, layoutmargins

I want to set margin to my main layout with programmatically. I use layout params as following code.

```java
val parMain = mainLayout?.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
```

But i have some error like

> android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

if I change the code as Android wants like this:

```java
val parMain = mainLayout?.layoutParams as ViewGroup.LayoutParams
```

There is no set margin function in my layoutParams.

Thats my xml code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_feed_scrool_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#99000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/detail_feed_view_pager_activity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i set margin in my case?

Comment: which one is mainLayout ?? detail_feed_scrool_view??

Comment: Yes it is.
var mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.detail_feed_scrool_view)

Comment: i think you are interested in why is that, don't you? so i'm providing the detailed answer

Comment: I tried to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams. Just error messages change like this:
android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: First of all, thanks for interested my question. I actually used Frame.LayoutParams on different constraintLayout in this project. But i do not know why i can not use in this view.

Comment: i explained the `LayoutParams` concept in answer, please check the answer now, you will be able to solve your problem afterword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Layout/View's `LayoutParams` depends on it's parent layout

**For example:-**

If you will try to get layout param from your `<View>` who have id `android:id="@+id/shadow_view"` then the `layoutParams` will be `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` type.

Why?  because `ConstraintLayout` is the parent layout of `<View>` . now same goes for the `<ViewPager>`, it's direct parent is also `ConstraintLayout`, so same `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`

and also when you want to set `layoutParams` on any View/Layout, Always look for the direct parent layout and set same as that parent layout type `layoutParams`

**Now Answer to Your Problem**

In your case, you don't have any parent layout that's why you are getting the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

`ViewGroup` is parent class of layouts, more like a generic class and this class don't have margins.

easiest solution for you will be just wrap your whole layout in another layout that you want, so there will be a parent for your `ConstraintLayout` and your `LayoutParams` will be the type of layout that you used to wrap

**something like this**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/detail_feed_scrool_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#99000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/detail_feed_view_pager_activity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now when you will try to get the `LayoutParams` you will get them as LinearLayout type

Comment: Okay i will try this answer. Thank you. I will feedback to here when i will try to your advice. Your answer look like so make sense for me.